# Displaying HTML that has been retrieved from a MySQL Database

Tags: html, mysql, angularjs

So I'm returning a string from a MySQL database as follows `<i>a</i><sup>2</sup> + <i>b</i><sup>2</sup> = <i>c</i><sup>2</sup>`

Unfortunately, the string is displayed in the browser as `<i>a</i><sup>2</sup> + <i>b</i><sup>2</sup> = <i>c</i><sup>2</sup>`.

The PHP file is as follows:

```
<?php
    require_once './config.php';

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `events`");
    $query->execute();

    $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo $json_response = json_encode($results);

?>
```

And this is this parsed in the JS controller using resource:

```
$scope.events = data;

$resource($scope.events).get().$promise.then(function (events) {
                        vm.events = events;
                    });
```

And it works in order to display things via an ngRepeat as follows:

```
<div class="container" id="visualization" ng-repeat="event in events">

            <div class="row">
                <div ng-class-odd="'col-md-6 col-md-offset-6'" ng-class-even="'col-md-6'">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            {{event.day}} {{event.month}} {{event.year}}
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-body">
                            {{event.description}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any help would be much, much appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT 1:

Given the below solution, the only things I change were in my controller file and in the view file itself, namely:

CONTROLLER FILE

```
var angular_module_name = angular.module('angular_module_name', []);

angular_module_name.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function (text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}]);
```

VIEW FILE

```
    <div class="container" id="visualization" ng-repeat="event in events">

        <div class="row">
            <div ng-class-odd="'col-md-6 col-md-offset-6'" ng-class-even="'col-md-6'">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        {{event.day}} {{event.month}} {{event.year}}
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <span class="description" ng-bind-html="event.description | to_trusted"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a filter:

```
.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function (text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
};
```

In html,

```
<div class="description" ng-bind-html="description | to_trusted"></div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much!